# Calling and Running Another python script and running all the code from it

Tags: python, jupyter

I am writing a python script on jupyter where the first script: a.ipynb has the majority of the analysis within, and multiple other scripts, which include the data cleaning [b.ipynb, c.ipynb, d.ipynb etc]. I am trying to call the data cleaning scripts [b.ipynb, c.ipynb, d.ipynb etc] into a.ipynb, but it keeps throwing errors.

I have tried some various different ways to read the data but these all are throwing errors:

```py
subprocess.getoutput([sys.executable,'d.ipynb'])

Error: "execution_count": null,\nNameError: name \'null\' is not defined'
```

```py
b_checks = open("d.ipynb", 'r').read()
exec(b_checks)

---> 21     exec(b_checks)
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

```py
exec(open('d.ipynb').read())

NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Currently, I am conditionally calling the scripts based on variable value as the data is imported from SQL and has multiple different properties `prop`

```py
# a.ipynb

prop = 'y'
#function to call data: checks
b_checks = checks(dbcon,prop)

if prop == 'w':
    b_checks = subprocess.getoutput([sys.executable, 'b.ipynb'])
elif prop =='x':
    b_checks = subprocess.getoutput([sys.executable, 'c.ipynb'])
elif prop == 'y':
    b_checks = subprocess.getoutput([sys.executable,'d.ipynb'])
elif prop == 'z':
    b_checks = subprocess.getoutput([sys.executable, 'e.ipynb'])
```

and the script I am trying to call at the moment is `d.ipynb` which includes the data cleaning of a certain column.

```
#d.ipynb
def  replace_server(to_r, server):
    return b_checks['Server'].str.replace(to_r, server)

b_checks['Server'] = b_checks['Server'].str.upper()
b_checks['Server'] = b_checks['Server'].str.strip()

b_checks['Server'] = replace_server('xxxx', 'x')
b_checks['Server'] = replace_server('123', 'x')
```

(there are more lines within this script)

My Current output of b_checks in the uncleaned dataset `xxxx, 123`, but the output I am hoping for is to run the entire second script `d.ipynb` so that the first script `a.ipynb` updates the variables in the b_checks table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a good practice to make a kind of API in another notebook:
say you have a func() in b.ipynb, and you need to call it from a.ipnyb, then 'a' notebook should contain:

```
%run ./b.ipynb
func()
```

Comment: because I have done the entire data cleaning in ```b.ipynb```, including calling the functions and replacing the required strings, I was hoping to call all that into ```a.ipynb``` so the ```a.ipynb``` will look cleaner and ```b_checks``` table updated with the cleaned data from ```b.ipynb```. When I run ```%%run ./b.ipynb```, it doesn't seem to update the ```b_checks``` table. Is there a way to include the second part with ```%run ./b.ipynb```

Comment: you can pack all your cleaning procedures and database requests into one single function within b.ipynb and name it say..def clean_data(). And then call it in a.ipynb using `%run ./b.ipynb` and then `clean_data()`

Answer (score 0):

I can not recommand you enough to store all this functions in real python scripts.
Let's say you have 3 Notebooks: `a.ipynb`, `b.ipynb` and `c.ipynb`

If you want in `c` to use functions stored in `a` or `b`, copy and pasted the functions (and all the imports needed) and save them in `a.py`, `b.py`

you can then easily `from a.py import funct_1, funct_2`

Their might be some solution to actually import functions directly from notebooks but i do not recommend that